# How to allow access to a localhost tcp port to one specific external IP address?

Tags: networking, server, proxy

Say we have a reddis server on `localhost`. We need to connect it from some other IPs. We know public IP of a node that we want to connect to our `localhost` `port` and have `sudo`. How to allow access to a localhost tcp port to one specific external IP address? And how to disable that access when we want?

Answer (score 1):

`ufw` can be used for this.

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.10 to any port 80
sudo ufw enable
```

will deny all traffic unless allowed, and then add a rule to allow traffic from 192.168.1.10 to port 80 on local machine. Note that this will block *new* ssh connections, unless you do a

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

which will open port 22 for incoming from any address.

`man ufw` in a terminal will bring up the manual page, describing all available options.